# Calculate $E[N_{i}]$ and then $f_i$ for all  in state spaces of the Markov chain depicted by the transition matrix.

Tags: probability, markov-chains, expected-value, transition-matrix

Specify the classes of the following Markov chain, and determine whether they are transient or recurrent, then calculate $E[N_{i}]$ and then $f_i$ for all  in state spaces of the Markov chain depicted by the transition matrix.

$\textbf{P} = \begin{Vmatrix}
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0\\
\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{Vmatrix},$

This is what I get for the classes and if they were recurrent or transient:

$S_1$ = {0,1}, recurrent. $S_2$ = {2}, recurrent. $S_3$ = {3}, transient. $S_4$ = {4}, transient.

Counting over all time, the total number of visits to state i, given that X0 = i, is given by an infinite sequence of indicator rvs $$N_i = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} I\{X_n = i|X_0 = i\}$$ and has a geometric distribution,
$$P(N_i = n) = f^{n−1}_{i}(1 − f_i), n ≥ 1.$$

Here, for any state $i$ we let $f_i$ denote the probability that, starting in state $i$, the process will ever reenter state $i$.

However, I am having problems finding $E[N_{i}]$ and $f_i$, can someone help me?

Comment: What is the meaning of $E[N_i]$ and $f_i$?

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Then it seems $f_i$ is defined as the probability of revisiting state $i$, given we start in state $i$.  Here you use the information you know about recurrence.  For example, what is $f_2$? $f_3$? $f_4$?