# Expected value of Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Question from professor that I need help with

> After answering exercise 14 calculate $E(N_i)$ and then $f_i$ for all $i$ in state spaces of the Markov chains depicted by the four transition matrices in exercise 14.

Question 14

> Specify the classes of the following Markov chains, and determine whether they are transient
>   or recurrent:

Partial Answer:

$$P_1=\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\end{bmatrix}$$ $S=\{0,1,2\}$ recurrent.

$$P_3=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\ \frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{4}&0&0\\ \frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\ 0&0&0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\ 0&0&0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\end{bmatrix}$$ $S_1=\{0,2\}$ recurrent.$S_2=\{3,4\}$ recurrent.$S_3=\{1\}$ transient.

---

Definitions:

$t_i= inf\{n\geq 1, X_n=i\}$ ,return time to state I

$f_i=P_i(t_i < \infty)$ ,probability that the Markov chain starting at $i$ will ever return to $i$

$N_i=$ number of visits to state $i$

---

I only gave two of the four transition matrices just to make it a bit shorter.

My question lies in how to go about solving my professors question.

Comment: Surely $N_i$ and $f_i$ are defined in your notes, textbook, etc. somewhere?

Comment: This seems similar to the following recent question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3582036/calculate-en-i-and-then-f-i-for-all-in-state-spaces-of-the-markov-cha?noredirect=1#comment7364649_3582036

Comment: after looking at my notes I will update the question to show his definitions for $N_i$ and $f_i$ @Math1000

Comment: Usually the first way to learn of recurrence/transience is in the probability that the Markov chain ever returns to state $i$.  This probability is 1 for a recurrent state (think about how this relates to an infinite number of visits to that state) and less than 1 for a transient state.

Comment: In short, if you have a recurrent state, you expect an infinite number of visits (if your chain begins at that state).  If your state is transient, you'll eventually never return so you expect a finite number of visits.  Different books/classes/lectures will approach this differently so I'm not sure how you need it answered, but it's something to know.  Your notation of $E(N_i)$ doesn't specify a starting state which i find strange since if you start in a class that $i$ isn't in, you expect $N_i = 0$ even if it's recurrent.

Comment: @Struggles Yes!  I was able to understand that part of the lecture. However regarding the problem my professor asked its easy enough to show that a transition matrix is recurrent or transient by just making a Markov chain graph. I'm having difficulty showing this rigorously aka showing what you mentioned above. My professor also further explained to use the mean of the geometric distribution, which was another curve ball in grasping his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be assuming that by $E(N_i)$ you mean $E_i(N_i)$ since that's the standard concept to be introduced at this point (just from where I gather you are in class).

In that case, let $f_{i}^k$ be $\mathbb{P}_i \left( t_{i}^k < \infty \right) $ i.e. that we have at least $k$ returns to $i$ when starting at $i$.

Then note $\mathbb{P}_i \left( N_i \geq k+1 \right) = f_{i}^{k+1}$.  It follows then that $\mathbb{P}_i \left( N_i \leq k \right) = 1 - f_{i}^{k+1}$.  Intuitively, this is saying that the probability we have at most $k$ returns to $i$ is equal to 1 minus the probability we have at least $k+1$ returns to $i$.

Now we note that $\mathbb{P}_i \left( N_i \leq k \right) = 1 - f_{i}^{k+1}$ is the CDF of $Geo(1 - f_i)$.  Now that we know that $N_i \vert_{X_0 = i} \sim Geo(1 - f_i)$ we use our knowledge of the expectation of a geometric distribution to get:

$$ E_i N_i = \frac{f_i}{1- f_i}$$

From here we can verify that if $f_i$ = 1 then we expect infinitely many returns.  Similarly if $f_i < 1$.  Now the issue will be finding $f_i$.  Depending on the structure of the chain this man involve a few additions of probabilities but shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: I was able to get the answer before looking at your solution,  but it's reassuring to see. we got the same result. Thank you for your explanations and your solution. All the best.